# I am unable to create google Line chart using data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I am trying to generate a google chart for the SQL table and unable to complete it. I had create a table which consists of X and Y values and i should get a line chart for the concerned X and Y values.There is a  error generated "table has no columns" and the graph is not generated.Can anyone help me for sorting this out?.Here goes my code:

Table creation :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Creating MySQL Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","GOGRAPHS");
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("GO_GRAPHS") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE graphs(x INT NOT NULL,y INT NOT NULL)")
or die(mysql_error());
echo"table created successfully";

mysql_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Insertion of data :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Creating MySQL Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("GO_GRAPHS") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO graphs(x, y)VALUES (10, 40),(20,60),(30,80)")
or die(mysql_error());  

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

converson of data in json (go_graphs_data.php):

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$sql)
{
    echo "Connection Not Created";
}
$con = mysql_select_db("GO_GRAPHS");
if(!$sql)
{
    echo "Database Not Connected";
}
$data[] = array('A','B');
$sql = "select * from graphs";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$data[] = array((int)$result['x'],(int)$result['y']);
}      

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Display of google graphs:

```
<html>

<head>

<!--Load the AJAX API-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(line_chart);

     function line_chart() {

      var jsonData = $.ajax({

          url: "go_graphs_data.php",

          dataType: "json",

          async: false

          }).responseText;

          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('linechart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});

    }

 </script>

</head>

<body>

<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->

<div id="linechart_div"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `url: ""go_graphs_data.php"` ?? too many `"`

Comment: i had changed it but no change in result

Comment: if the data is being correctly inserted into the db then I'd suggest using the console to debug the ajax function. Is there a valid json response being sent back from the php script? Also, what is `$data[] = array('A','B');` ? The remaining data is numeric is it not?

Comment: yes the data is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

when creating a google-vis DataTable directly from json...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

the json must be in a specific format, [found here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

in this case, it appears you're building a simple array

as such, use the [static method `arrayToDataTable`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#assortedmethods) instead

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
```

note: since the method is static, no need for the `new` keyword

**EDIT**

if the data does not contain column headings, be sure to set the second argument to `true` (`firstRowIsData`)...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData, true);
```

**EDIT 2**

see following working snippet using all numbers...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawBasic,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawBasic() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');

  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
    [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
    [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
    [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
    [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
    [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
    [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
    [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66],
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      top: 12,
      right: 12,
      bottom: 36,
      left: 24,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.Error has fixed.,but no visual graph is obtained. I think there is problem with JSON array .Can you once check it out and help me

Comment: No error found. I am trying to create data chart for X and Y which are both numerics.Is it possible? .Every example in internet shows me datachart for String vs numerics

Comment: it's possible, see __EDIT 2__ above, will you please share a sample of `jsonData` being fed to the chart?

Comment: I Dont want to add manually all the data using "data.addRows".I like to have it from table.

Comment: yes, understood, just an example to demonstrate using all numeric values works -- if you could edit the question with the latest javascript and a sample of `jsonData` then i can get the chart working...